# How to deploy to azure signalr service from visual studio or via command line

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-deployment, signalr-service

I have been trying to find some guide or article on how to deploy code on azure signalr service. Currently I am using azure app service for signalr which is temporary alternative for development only. I cant see signalr service instances (that I have created from azure portal) during publish in visual studio.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: this video is really helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpQZrQ6Wnbw

Comment: If it is resolved, you could add and accept it as an answer to let more communities easily to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer as suggested.
I have figured out the answer to this, if we enable some configuration in signalr app like userAzureSignalr it deploys the code to the signalr service instance within the same resourse group otherwise you can specify connection string of the signalr service instance where you want this to run. As per my understanding you need at least one app service instance to deploy your code and the hub related code will run on signalr service instance and you would be able to see the traffic in signalr service.